# Display data in csv base on foreign key and also occurence, should be in a row for each user

Tags: mysql, csv, php-5.5

i want to display data in csv, now a user can have multiple loans each loan has an ID, so basically i need is count each loan_id for each user and on a single ROW display the data base on the no of the count, on thesame row if the user has another loan with a different ID do the same and display the data untill you are through with that user and move to the next row for another user like that....
[image: this is the data i'm fetching from]

//this the query

```
$getLoans = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM loans WHERE acctno = '$acctno'");
        $loan_id = array();
        $loan_acc = "";
        $loan_amount = "";
        while ($loanRow = mysql_fetch_assoc($getLoans)) {
            $loan_id[$acctno] = $loanRow['loan_id'];
            $loan_amount = $loanRow['amount'];
            $loan_acc = $loanRow['acctno'];
        }

        $gottenAmounts2 = array();
        $gottenDates2 = array();
        $recordCount = array();
        $loopCount = 0;
        foreach ($loan_id as $acct => $lid) {
            $gLive___ = mysql_query("SELECT loan_id, COUNT(*) AS live_c FROM repayments WHERE loan_id = '$lid' AND acctno = '$acct' ");
            while ( $gLive___2 = mysql_fetch_assoc($gLive___)){
                $recordCount[$lid] = $gLive___2['live_c'];
            }


            $getRe = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM repayments WHERE loan_id ='$lid' AND acctno = '$acct' ");
              while ($getRes = mysql_fetch_assoc($getRe)) {
                
                    $gottenAmounts2[] = $getRes['amount'];
                    $gottenDates2[] = $getRes['date'];
                    
                
            }
            
        }
```

//this the logic to display in csv,

```
foreach ($recordCount as $l => $rr) {
            foreach ($LiveCount as $loan_acc => $kive) {
                if (!isset($userData[$loan_acc])) {
                    $userData[$loan_acc] = array(
                        "NAME" => $ahafa,
                        "ACCOUNT NO" => $loan_acc,
                        "TOTAL" => $balZ_,
                    );
                    
            

                    for ($i = 0; $i < $kive; $i++) {
                        $userData[$loan_acc]["LOAN TYPE $i"] = isset($loan_type[$i]) ? $loan_type[$i] : '';
        
                        for ($j = 0; $j < $rr; $j++) {
                            $userData[$loan_acc]["TRXN $i-$j"] = isset($gottenAmounts2[$j]) ? $gottenAmounts2[$j] : '';
                            $userData[$loan_acc]["DATE $i-$j"] = isset($gottenDates2[$j]) ? $gottenDates2[$j] : '';
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

the result i have is it returns the same data for each user, if user A as 3 loan_id and on each loan_id the transactions 4, 8 and 5. respectively. the loop gets the first 4 transactions and repeat the same transaction for second and third one, it dosen't go back to pick the rest only works with the first